# How to remove a break line in coding

Tags: programming, output-formatting

```
MySum[p_List, iMin_] := Module[{printOuput, i, iMax},
   iMax = iMin + Length[p];
   printOuput = "";
   For[i = iMin, i < iMax, i++,
    printOuput = 
     printOuput <> " + " <> ToString[i, TraditionalForm] <> 
      " \[CenterDot] " <> 
      ToString[Part[p, i - iMin + 1], TraditionalForm]];
   Print[printOuput <> " = "];
   Sum[Part[p, i - iMin + 1]*i, {i, iMin, iMax - 1}]];
p = 1/7 {3, 2, 0, 2};
MySum[p, 0]
```

This is my code.

1. I would like to have it in one separate line.
2. I would also like to remove the first "+",

So the output will look exactly like this:

$$0 \cdot \frac{3}{7} + 1 \cdot \frac{2}{7} + 2 \cdot 0 + 3 \cdot \frac{2}{7}= \frac{8}{7}$$

Comment: Get rid of the `Print[...]` line and change the next one to `StringDrop[printOuput, 2] <> " = " <> ToString[Sum[...], TraditionalForm]`

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative for you to consider:

```
mySum[p_List, iMin_] :=
  Sum[CenterDot[i + iMin - 1, p[[i]]], {i, Length@p}] //
    Row[{#, Times @@@ #}, "\[LongEqual]"] &

mySum[1/7 {3, 2, 0, 2}, 0]
```

[image]

---

Thanks for the Accept.  Since you found this helpful I'd like to make sure you understand it.

The function [`CenterDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CenterDot.html) formats objects as implied, and by default it has no meaning so it will not evaluate to anything.  This is used in `Sum` which you are already familiar with. (If you watched the evolution of this answer you saw that originally I used `MapIndexed`, which is equally applicable, but I thought `Sum` would be more comfortable.)

The second important bit is the function `Row[{#, Times @@@ #}, "\[LongEqual]"] &`.
[`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html) itself is a formatting function that puts objects in a row, optionally with a separating character.
`Times @@@ #` replaces the heads at level one (here `CircleDot`) with `Times` effecting the evaluation of the sum.

Comment: +1,you shall write some book or some Mathematica articles.